# How to show all columns in CollectionView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have List with decent amount of columns (13 to be exact)
When I populate my collection view I have problem because only 3-4 columns are visible, and I can't scroll collection view horizontally. I tried to improvise something using scroll view but it just made each row scrollable separatly like its not bound to header and other data in view, How to achive this kind of horizontall scroll?

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | ... | C_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **** | **** | **** |  |  |  |
| **** | **** | **** |  |  |  |
| **** | **** | **** |  |  |  |

My CollectionVeiw code sample

```
                <CollectionView WidthRequest="1000" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" BackgroundColor="White" ItemsSource="{Binding output}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" EmptyView="No data">

                <CollectionView.Header>

                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#F5F9FF" Grid.Row="2" RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="50,90,100,30,35,70,100,100,100,100,100,100,100" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="2">
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="0" Text="C1"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Text="C2"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="2" Text="C3 организације"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="3" Text="C4"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="4" Text="C5"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="5" Text="C6"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="6" Text="C7"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="7" Text="C8"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="8" Text="C9"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="9" Text="C10"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="10" Text="C11"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="11" Text="C12"/>
                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="12" Text="C13"/>
                    </Grid>

                </CollectionView.Header>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate  >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:AmanetProveraDocument_Select_Output" >
                        <Grid  RowDefinitions="40" ColumnDefinitions="50,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="2">
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding D1, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding D2, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding D3, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding D4, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding D5, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding D6, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding D7, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding D8, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding D9, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="9" Text="{Binding D10, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="10" Text="{Binding D11, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="11" Text="{Binding D12, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="12" Text="{Binding D13, Converter = {StaticResource NullToStringConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <!--</StackLayout>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: you need to use a DataGrid

Comment: @Jason Can you give me some code sample, I am not that experienced with xamarin

Comment: DataGrid is a different type of control.  There are some free versions available on nuget, as well as several commercial offerings.  Google "xamarin datagrid"

Comment: Oh, but is there way using native xamarin forms?

Comment: Take a look at [CollectionView Horizontal grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid) , maybe helpful .

Comment: Tried but using this I get, header on left, and rows right from it scrollable horizontally but after reaching max height it add new "column with rows" on right

Comment: Finally used Nuget Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid, but know I am stuck with DataGrid.ItemSelected property.
I am using MVVM pattern with Commands, but DataGrid needs EventHandler for ItemSelected (I hope this is alternative for SelectionChangedCommand in CollectionView). Is there way to use existing command as ItemSelected or if not how should I implement it using MVVM, main goal of command should be to update value of some IsSelected boolean value